# Hosting WCF Service online for use from a Windows Phone 8 device

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8, web-hosting

I can't seem to get my Windows Phone 8 app to successfully connect to my wcf service, and I'm wondering if it is because I haven't yet started paying to host the wcf service online. I can connect to the service when I use the WP8 emulator, but not when I load the app onto a device. Should the device be working or do you think it's because I am not yet hosting the service online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that's because your wcf service is accessed through `localhost` when using the emulator.
Then, your device has no access to `localhost`, if I'm not mistaken, which could explain why your device could not connect to the service.
The way to solve this could be to host your service online, as you've already figured.